# Using inner Join in Solr query

Tags: sql, join, solr, lucene, inner-join

In SQL, I have the query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON 
     table1.table1To2Id = table2.table2Id INNER JOIN 
     table3 ON table1.table1To3Id = table3.table3Id
```

How can I make the same query using Solr? Given that the field in SQL is the same field in Solr
Thank in advance

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636637/solr-join-query?rq=1

Comment: I don't think it duplicates, since in my cases, I don't want to change the document structure, and it requires join query between 3 documents

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE id IN (SELECT bookId 
             FROM bookauthors 
             WHERE authorId IN (SELECT authorId 
                                FROM author 
                                WHERE author.name LIKE '%Rowling%'))
```

Solr (split to multiple lines for readabilty):

```
http://<code>hostname:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&fq= 
{!join+from=bookId+to=id}
authorId:{!join+from=authorId+to=authorId}
author.name:Rowling
```

The key is to pass in the next join query after `:` instead of passing the value. For more information refer to [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-JoiningAcrossCollections)

Comment: +1 The reference you cited only has a few more examples, but no definitive guide. Is there some other place to find Solr manuals, esp. for more complex features? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to update the documentation? Link no longer works

Comment: @user3166881, Thanks! Updated the link.